# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed — process out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forever

To download as csv file, i dont know what is the issue, its working fine when users is 40,000 records, when ever im trying to hit the api(80,000 records) its showing process out of memory. please help me with this issue

```
  app.get('/excelData', function (req, result) {
 var fields = ['firstName','lastName','catalina_cardStatus','deviceType','appVerison','phoneNumber','emailAddress','language','state','lastLogin','dateOfBirth']
 var data = [];
   var status = true;
   User.find({accountType:'user',isDeleted: {$ne:{status}}}).sort({created: -1}).exec((err, res) => {
     var resultData = [];
         var len = res.length;
         res.map((user,key) =>{
       var resData = {};
       if(user) {
         resData.firstName = user.firstName;
         resData.lastName = user.lastName;
         resData.catalina_cardStatus = user.catalina_cardStatus;
         resData.language = user.language;
         resData.phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
         resData.deviceType = user.deviceType;
         resData.appVerison = user.appVerison;
         resData.emailAddress = user.emailAddress;
         resData.state = user.state;
         resData.dateOfBirth = user.dateOfBirth;
         if(user.lastLogin){
           var date = new Date(user.lastLogin);
           var utcDate = new Date(date.toISOString());
           var utc = utcDate.setHours(utcDate.getHours()-8);
           var usDate = utc;
             var time = moment(utc).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
             resData.lastLogin = time;
         }
 }
          resultData.push(resData);
          len--;
          if(len==0){
                var csv = json2csv({ data:resultData , fields: fields });
                fs.writeFile('path', csv, function(err,data) {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      fs.unlinkSync('path'.csv');
                    }, 30000);
                    result.send({msg: "saved sucessfully",path :'path.csv'});
                  if (err)
                  {
                    throw err;
                    console.log("Error: "+err);
                  }
                })
          }

     })
 })

 });
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when the memory allocated for the execution application is less than the required memory when run application.

By default the memory limit in Node.js is 512 mb, to solve this issue you need to increasing the memory limit use command `—- max-old-space-size` .It can be avoid the memory limit issue.

```
node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js #increase to 1gb
node --max-old-space-size=2048 index.js #increase to 2gb
node --max-old-space-size=3072 index.js #increase to 3gb
node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js #increase to 4gb
node --max-old-space-size=5120 index.js #increase to 5gb
node --max-old-space-size=6144 index.js #increase to 6gb
node --max-old-space-size=7168 index.js #increase to 7gb
node --max-old-space-size=8192 index.js #increase to 8gb
```

Comment: Try reading xlsx file row by row with this lib: https://github.com/ffalt/xlsx-extract

If above failed, try https://github.com/extrabacon/xlrd-parser

Comment: @susmithapanda Make sure you're putting the `--max-old-space-size` flag *before* `index.js`, otherwise the flag gets passed to your program rather than to the node.js runtime. That said, I'm also running into similar problems even with correct flag usage. Will report back if I find a solution.